# Question about derivation of Fourier transform

Tags: vector-spaces, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, orthonormal

I'm reading the book "Fourier Analysis and Its Applications" and in the derivation of the Fourier transform he began with writing the Fourier series $$f(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty }^{\infty }c_{n}exp(in\frac{\pi}{P}t)$$

where  $$c_{n}=\frac{1}{2P}\int_{-P}^{P}f(t)exp({-in\frac{\pi}{P}t)}dt$$

so we're projecting our function on the orthogonal basis  in infinite dimensional function space

he then defined a function $$f
(P, ω) = \int_{-P}^{P}f(t)e^{-iwt}dt$$
then he re wrote the Fourier series  as $$f(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{n=-\infty }^{\infty }f
(P, ω_{n})exp(iw_{n}t).\frac{\pi}{P},, w_{n}=\frac{n\pi}{P}$$

which is equal
$$f(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty }^{\infty }\frac{\Delta w}{2\pi} \begin{pmatrix}
  \int_{-\frac{\pi}{\Delta w}}^{\frac{\pi}{\Delta w}}f(t).exp({-in\Delta wt)}dt\end{pmatrix}  .exp(in\Delta wt)$$

then he took the limit as $\Delta w \longrightarrow 0$ which made the integral inside the braces become the Fourier transform formula

but how did the term $n \Delta w$ after we took the limit become just continuous $w$ ?

and the idea of Fourier series is to write the function in terms of orthogonal basis how our basis change after we took the limit , is it become a continuum of basis ? but that doesn't make sense because the basis must be n- dimensional

Comment: As for the comment about the basis being $n$-dimensional, that is not true. First, it does not make sense to say a basis is $n$-dimensional, since a basis doesn't have a dimension, it has a cardinality. The space itself (for which the basis is a basis) has the dimension. Second, $n$ is not a fixed value here. Third, we're working in function spaces with infinite dimension.

Comment: Here, $\pi/P=\Delta w$. We want to take the limit as $P\to\infty$. But as $\Delta w\to 0^+$, the argument $-in\pi t/P$ doesn't do anything useful if we simply take $P\to \infty$. What we're going to do is fix a $\xi$ and then look at combinations of $n$ and $P$ such that $n/P\to \xi$. Then the integral $$\int_{-P}^P f(t)\exp(-in\pi t/P)dt \to \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\exp(-i\pi t\xi)dt,$$ precisely because we chose to take $n,P$ to $\infty$ in a smart way together.

Comment: @jwhite, I know we're working with infinite dimension , but it's quantized which takes values like 1,2,3.......... infinity, but if we make the difference is going to zero, it won't be quantized any more

Comment: At no point are we in a finite dimensional space.

Comment: @jwhite, could you explain the trick of $P$,$n$ in more detail, because I couldn't understand what you wrote

Comment: As another comment on the basis/dimension, I believe you're talking about countable vs. continuum. However, an expansion $f(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n e_n(t)$ does not mean that the space in question has countable dimension. A basis is such that every vector in the space has to have a **finite** linear combination in terms of the basis. Here $f=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n e_n$ is not a finite linear combination. One can actually show by the Baire category theorem that a Banach space cannot have a countably infinite basis.

Comment: For a fixed $\xi>0$ and each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, let $P_n=\xi n$, so $n/P_n=\xi$ and $P_n\to \infty$ as $n\to\infty$. Then the sum $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty f(P_n,w_m)\exp(iw_m t)\cdot \frac{\pi}{P_n}$$ includes the term $$\int_{-P_n}^{P_n} f(t)\exp(-i n \pi t/P_n)dt = \int_{-P_n}^{P_n} f(t)\exp(-i\pi t\xi) dt.$$ Sending $P_n\to\infty$ turns the right hand side into $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\exp(-i\pi t\xi)dt.$$

We can do something similar for $\xi<0$ and $n\to\infty$. $\xi=0$ is easy to deal with as the $n=0$ term.

Comment: @jwhite, but in the expansion we can't put a non-integer number , the expansion is done at n=1,2... And so forth

Comment: Where did I put a non-integer in the series?

Comment: @jwhite, integrating over the whole $w$ took into consideration that our basis no more quantized by the factor $n$, it take every value of $w$ which is a continuum of it

Comment: In what sense do you have a basis? What is the basis? What space is it a basis for? What do you mean by "quantized"?

The reason the sum $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \ldots$ becomes an integral is because these are Riemann sums. They converge to the integral over all $\mathbb{R}$ because that's what Riemann sums do.

Comment: @jwhite, a the basis function is just like a basis of a vector which that any function could be written as inner product multiplied by that basis and summing over all the basis, if it's infinite dimensional so the sum goes from n=0,1,2,3....

Comment: Please answer the questions I asked.

Comment: @jwhite, I am studying from the playlist of prof Steve Brunton from Washington university and the definition  i know is in that video https://youtu.be/7ICYxBuS2iw?si=mJSNdGPHRhX_eezH

Comment: What is the basis? What space it is a basis for?